# CSS3 transparent border that overrides all layers of elements underneath it

Tags: html, css, border, transparent

I was wondering if something as seen in the image is possible to do in CSS - 
the white background is actually transparent. The 2 small circles have a transparant border - this is done in photoshop, but in css, the transparent border will "reveal" the black circle underneath - so basically what i'm asking is if it is possible to "override" all the layers underneath the transparent background "all the way" down to the base layer.

Thanks !

[image]

Comment: If you only want to use the "transparency" in this scenario, then you could just put slightly larger white circles underneath the blue and green ones. If you actually want a sort of modular "parent-overriding transparency", then you're unfortunately out of luck.

Comment: nop, unfortunately it has to be really transparent...

Comment: JavaScript to the rescue, then!

Comment: how would you accomplish this in JS?

Comment: Hmm... I would think you'd maybe have to use `canvas`, and you could constantly check for the center of the blue and green circles, then clear them, then clear a circle with the same center as the small circles but a larger radius (this would create the transparency effect), then repaint the circles. Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Not with HTML and CSS alone, no.

It might be possible with SVG and paths. But that is beyond the scope of a single answer.

Comment: Before you start telling me that this is a comment. This is not a comment. It answer the question. Yes I'm talking to **you**.